# query object does not working with dynamic column name

Tags: python, django

```
qs_new  = MODEl_NAME.objects.all()
j=1
for query_value in qs_new:
    k=0

    for field in model_obj._meta.fields:                        
        fieldname = field.get_attname_column()
        ws.write(0, k, fieldname[0])                   
        ws.write(j, k, query_value.fieldname[1])
        k= k +1

j=j+1
```

error at `query_value.fieldname[1]` and if I put `query_value.first_name` it's working fine.
What is wrong with that (`query_value.filedname[1]`)?

Comment: And what is the full traceback of the error then?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Locator' object has no attribute 'fieldname'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`getattr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to look up attributes dynamically:

```
ws.write(j, k, getattr(query_value, fieldname[1]))
```

`getattr()` will look up the attribute named in `fieldname[1]` on the object `query_value`.

Comment: after using getattr(query_value,fieldname[1]).    its giving another error: Exception: Unexpected data type <class 'django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile'>

Comment: @AshishSaxena: you probably meant to use `fieldname[0]`; item `1` is the field object.

Comment: @AshishSaxena: updated; there is a `.name` attribute on the `Field` instances.

Comment: raise Exception("Unexpected data type %r" % type(label))

Exception: Unexpected data type <class 'django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile'>

Comment: @AshishSaxena: Wait, what code is throwing this exception? `fieldname` is a tuple of two strings, only `field` is the `Field` instance.

Comment: File "/home/ubuntu/django-apps/hive/../hive/apps/reports/forms.py", line 459, in get_itable
    ws.write(j, k, getattr(query_value, fieldname[0].name))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: @AshishSaxena: exactly, so use `fieldname[1]` then.

Comment: i am using      ws.write(j, k, getattr(query_value, fieldname[1].name))  

ws.write(j, k, getattr(query_value, fieldname[0].name))  


in both case getting error

Comment: if i am using getattr(query_value, fieldname[1]) getting error :  raise Exception("Unexpected data type %r" % type(label))

Exception: Unexpected data type <class 'django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile'>

Comment: Yes, I already removed the `.name` part; the comment with `Exception: Unexpected data type` was confusing.

Comment: You are getting a [`FieldFile` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile) and you cannot write those to your output file as-is; you may want to skip those.

Comment: You need to be clear in what you want to do here, your question is lacking in enough detail. Your query results cannot be written to a file because one of the field values is a `FieldFile` object. Either *read* the data from that file and copy that over too, or skip such values.

Comment: @AshishSaxena: Not in your Django model, you haven't. The table will only have the filename, but there is an actual file on disk too.